# SOR method converges for $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}2& -1\\-2 & 2\end{array} \right)$

Tags: matrices

Prove that the SOR method converges in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for the matrix
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}2& -1\\-2 & 2\end{array} \right)$ iff $\omega\in(0,2)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the usual splitting of $A$ in the form $A=D+L+U$ to the diagonal, lower and upper triangular part, the iteration matrix of SOR is
$$
T=(D+\omega L)^{-1}[(1-\omega)D-\omega U].
$$
Hence
$$
T =
\begin{bmatrix}
1 - \omega & \frac{\omega}{2} \\
\omega(1-\omega) & 1 - \omega + \frac{\omega^2}{2}
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The characteristic polynomial of $T$ is
$$
p(\lambda)=\lambda^2-\lambda\left(\frac{\omega^2}{2}-2\omega+2\right)+(\omega-1)^2.
$$
I invite you to show that the roots $\lambda_+$ and $\lambda_-$ of $p$ satisfy $|\lambda_{\pm}|<1$ for $\omega\in(0,2)$.

Comment: I can prove that if p(T)<1, we need $\omega\in(0,2)$,but I don't know how to prove the counter direction.

Comment: Try expressing the eigenvalues of $T$ in terms of $\omega$.

Comment: I use mathematical to solve it,thanks.